# How to redirect to existing locale in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When I type `myweb.com/ru/wrong_link` it redirects me now to `myweb.com/en/` instead of the existing locale `ru`.

In my application.rb:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :ru]
```

How can I do that it redirects me, if `site.com/en/wrong_link` to `site.com/en`, but if `site.com/ru/wrong_link` to `site.com/ru`?

I have in my application_controller:

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  if (params[:locale] != "en") && (params[:locale] != "ru")
    redirect_to "/en"
  else
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post your `routes.rb`

Comment: Instead of `redirect_to "/en"` try: `redirect_to root_url(params[:locale])` or `redirect_to "/#{params[:locale]}"`

Comment: @Surya, your suggestion is wrong, what if the locale doesn't exist?

Comment: @p4sh4 http://pastebin.com/wN2AnYuy this is my route

Comment: @p4sh4 You're right. @Orkhan : You can do `redirect_to root_url(I18n.locale)` or `redirect_to "/#{I18n.locale}"` instead. My bad.

Comment: Try `match '*path' => redirect("/#{I18n.locale}/"), :via => "get"`

Comment: @p4sh4 no, it still redirects me to the "en" instead of "ru" =/

Comment: Hmm, do you have any other redirects in your code? According to your `routes.rb`,`myweb.com/ru/wrong_link` would actually hit `get '/:locale/:id/'` and `wrong_link` would be interpreted as the `:id` parameter. You can try logging the current locale, maybe during that redirect `I18n.locale` is actually set to `en` so you're getting a redirect to it

Answer (score 1):

Your `set_locale` method will redirect to "/en" for every request which doesn't pass `params[:locale]` through.  Eg if you go to

```
  post '/feed/:id/comments/', to: 'home#create_comment'
```

then set_locale will be called first.  params[:locale] is equal to nil, so the test will be equivalent to

```
if (nil != "en") && (nil != "ru")
```

which will evaluate to `true` and so cause the request to be redirected.

In this case the path is "/ru/wrong_link".  The way routes works is that the first matching route is used.  In the case of your route file, this looks like

```
get '/:locale/:id/', except: 'search', to: 'home#by_category', as: 'category'
```

which will interpret that path as going to home#by_category, setting params to {:locale => "ru", :id => "wrong_link"}

Is that what is actually happening?  You should be able to see the sequence of events in your log.

Comment: In the case of `post '/feed/:id/comments/'`, wouldn't `params[:locale]` be equal to `feed`?

Comment: Actually yes, you're right.  It's still producing unexpected results, though, just via a different set of params.  The point remains that the routing and the way of handling locale are very fragile.